# Default user after reboot in multi-user CM 12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, multi-user

I setup a new user on my tablet in order to use it as a wall tablet with some smart home informations und buttons.

Unfortunately after reboot the Owner is always the user who is started first. So I have to change to another user in order to run the information app after every reboot.

Is there a way to change the default user which the CM is starting by after reboot?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which is ok for me. I execute the following line using Script Manager App on Boot. This switches the user to the one with ID=10.

```
am switch-user 10
```

User ID's can be found with this command:

```
pm list users
```

Both commands have to be run as root.